# Force UIView to draw with specific scale (1 point = 1 pixel)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, cgcontext, cgimage

I'm doing a barcode printing feature, it generates a barcode view and then send the pixels data to the thermal printer. The process is below:

1. Snapshot `UIView` with size 250x90 (points) to `UIImage`:

```swift
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: view.bounds)
let image = renderer.image { rendererContext in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

2. Get pixels data of output image:

```swift
extension UIImage {
    func pixelData() -> [UInt8]? {
        let height = self.size.height
        let width = self.size.width
        let dataSize = width * height
        var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(dataSize))
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let bitmapInfo: UInt32 = 0
        
        let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,
                                width: Int(width),
                                height: Int(height),
                                bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                bytesPerRow: Int(width),
                                space: colorSpace,
                                bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
        context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        
        return pixelData
    }
}
```

3. Send `pixelData` to printer (after some process to convert it to printer data, like which pixel is black/white/gray...)

The problem is that, the size of the output bitmap must be fixed to 250x90 pixels, so it can be fit in the label stamp. But in high resolution iPhones with screen scale of 3x, after called `pixelData()` with 250x90 as width/height, the output `CGImage` will be downscale from original `cgImage` (because the original has 750x270 pixels). And because of downscaling, some black area become gray, and barcode becomes unrecognizable.

I can put the `image.scale` to `pixelData()` method, but that will make the pixels data to have the physical size of 750x270 pixels and it too large to fit in the label stamp.

I also tried this way to create `UIImage` but it still downscales and pixelates the output image:

```swift
// force 1.0 scale
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 1.0)
drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return image
```

So the question is:

- Can I force the `UIView` to be drawn with 1x scale, as 1 point = 1 pixel, and everything after that will working as expected?
- Or can I adjust the pixels data generation so that `context.draw` can merge 3 pixels into 1?

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked, but why do you need to do any snapshotting at all? If your app knows how to generate a barcode view, why doesn't it just draw the barcode from scratch, again, but at the right scale for the printer? I have an app that does USPS barcodes and that's what it does. The screen resolution is irrelevant.

Comment: @matt thanks for the suggestion, actually the printer has its own command to print barcode, but my view is a custom view with some (rather complex) information, so my best way is to generate UIImage and print its bitmap instead of just send the barcode command. It's fine for other information to be pixelated but not the barcode.